# How to adjust alignment to right for a text entered in the JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to set the alignment of my text to right. Actually the fields are related to currency so if it starts from right, it will look good.

```
PreparedStatement stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("select sum(tv)as totalsum from mut_det WHERE rm_id = ?");
            ResultSet rs1;
            String rm1 = tf_rm_id.getText().trim();
            stmt1.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(rm1));
            rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
            while (rs1.next()) {
                String text = rs1.getString("totalsum");
                tf_rsfig.setText(text);

            }
```

Answer (score 35):

```
jTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html#RIGHT))

Answer (score 4):

This should align all text you entered in JTextField to right:

```
JTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

it works the same as SwingConstants.RIGHT
but thought if we know we are working with JTextField then be specific.

tf_rsfig.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);